# Writing a File to a local share from a webserver

Tags: php, ftp

I am trying to write a file to a local share using PHP and a webserver. The origin of the file is the webserver ubuntu01 and a share on my local machine 7PD01-2012 is where the file is to be written. The path "ftp://ryan:pass@7PD01-2012//file.txt" resolves when I put it in a web browser and displays the file contents. There does not seem to be a permissions issue. I am able to ping the webserver from the client and the client from the webserver. FTP is installed on my ubuntu webserver and Filezille ftp Server is installed on the client. Using filezilla or the browser I am able to ftp to both locations. I have setup firewall rules on the webserver and updated the /etc/hosts file. Any ideas what could be causing these errors?

```
        $fileName = "ftp://ryan:pass@7PD01-2012//file.txt";
        is_dir($fileName);
        if (($myfile = fopen($fileName, "w")) === false) { //open the file
            //if unable to open throw exception
            throw new RuntimeException("Could Not Open File Location on Server.");
        }
```

( ! ) Warning: is_dir(): connect() failed: Connection timed out in /var/www/html/CDprinter/processor.php on line 143

( ! ) Warning: fopen(): connect() failed: Connection timed out in /var/www/html/CDprinter/processor.php on line 144

( ! ) Warning: fopen(ftp://...@10.162.12.130//file.txt): failed to open stream: operation failed in /var/www/html/CDprinter/processor.php on line 144

Comment: Use FTP. http://php.net/ftp

Comment: Used FTP as a work around ... which lead me to discover that it was the clients firewall rules for port 20 and 21...